# SSH, run process and then ignore the output

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, terminal, stdout

I have a command that will SSH and run a script after SSH'ing. The script runs a binary file.

Once the script is done, I can type any key and my local terminal goes back to its normal state. However, since the process is still running in the machine I SSH'ed into, any time it logs to `stdout` I see it in my local terminal.

How can I ignore this output without monkey patching it on my local machine by passing it to `/dev/null`? I want to keep the output inside the machine I am SSH'ing to and I want to just leave the SSH altogether after the process starts. I can pass it to `/dev/null` in the machine, however.

This is an example of what I'm running:

```
cat ./sh/script.sh | ssh -i ~/.aws/example.pem ec2-user@11.111.11.111
```

The contents of `script.sh` looks something like this:

```
# Some stuff...

# Run binary file
./bin/binary &
```

Comment: I think  ./bin/binary >output.txt 2>&1 &  should do it.

Comment: Hmm that seems to just make it hang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it with `./bin/binary &>/dev/null &`

Comment: Didn't the question specify "without passing it to `/dev/null`"? I read it to be asked in a way that specifically excluded this answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes you're right, I meant more specifically without just passing it to `/dev/null` on my local machine. It can be passed there within the EC2 instance, however. It was basically implying I didn't just want to monkey patch the problem locally. Updating question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the script to the remote machine and then run it remotely. Following commands are executed on your local machine.

```
 $ scp -i /path/to/sshkey /some/script.sh user@remote_machine:/path/to/some/script.sh

 # Run the script in the background on the remote machine and pipe the output to a logfile. This will also exit from the SSH session right away.
 $ ssh -i /path/to/sshkey \
    user@remote_machine "/path/to/some/script.sh &> /path/to/some/logfile &"
```

Note, `logfile` will be created on the remote machine.

```
 # View the log file while the process is executing
 $ ssh -i /path/to/sshkey user@remote_machine "tail -f /path/to/some/logfile"
```