# Run shell commands in a remote machine

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to know how can I run shell commands in a remote machine.
I tried this:

```
ssh prdcrm1@${server} "grep -l 'Sometthing' *"
```

It is working, but I want to run more commands.
Do someone has an Idea?

Comment: Create a script, copy it to remote machine and then run it remotely using `ssh`. See this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412836/ssh-run-process-and-then-ignore-the-output/

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple commands on remote machine like,

Run date and hostname commands:

```
$ ssh user@host "date && hostname"
```

Run a script called /scripts/backup.sh

```
ssh user@host '/scripts/backup.sh'
```

Run sudo or su command using the following syntax

```
ssh user@host su --session-command="/sbin/service httpd restart"
ssh -t user@host 'sudo command1 arg1 arg2' ## su syntax ##
```

Multi-line command with variables expansion

```
VAR1="Variable 1"
ssh $HOST bash -c "'
ls
pwd
if true; then
    echo $VAR1
else
    echo "False"
fi
'"
```

Hope these helps you.